# Can Mathematica calculate this elliptic, triple integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

```
Integrate[(4 a b/Pi) (a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c])^(1/2), {a, 0, 1}, {b, 
  0, 1}, {c, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

I'm using basic plan, it gives me the result like that.
The approximate is 0.9054... but I want exact value with closed form.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible

Comment: Actually it is possible, see my answer below, and the result is exactly $128/(45\pi)$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Doing the Integrals separately for a, b and c gives the answer $\frac{128}{45 \pi}\sim 0.905415$, which agrees with the numerical estimate from NIntegrate:

```
NIntegrate[(4 a b/Pi) (a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c])^(1/2), {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, Pi}]
```

> 0.905415

In a nutshell, the trick is to do the integrals separately as indefinite and then take the limits properly. This is a somewhat straight-forward integral and the trick works, in more general cases, caution is advised!

In more detail:
First do the integral over $a$:

```
inta = Integrate[(4 a b/Pi) (a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c])^(1/2), a]
```

> (1/(3 [Pi]))b (Sqrt[a^2 + b^2-2 a b Cos[c]] (4 a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c] - 3 b^2 Cos[2 c]) + 6 b^3 Cos[c] Log[a - b Cos[c] + Sqrt[a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c]]] Sin[c]^2)

and then the one over b:

```
intb = Integrate[(inta /. a -> 1) - (inta /. a -> 0), b] // PowerExpand
```

> (1/(15 [Pi]))(b^5 (-1 + 3 Cos[2 c]) + Sqrt[1 + b^2 - 2 b Cos[c]] (1 + 8 b^2 + b^4 - 2 (b + b^3) Cos[c] - 3 (1 + b^4) Cos[2 c]) -  6 b^5 Cos[c] Log[b - b Cos[c]] Sin[c]^2 + 6 Cos[c] Log[b - Cos[c] + Sqrt[1 + b^2 - 2 b Cos[c]]] Sin[c]^2 +  6 b^5 Cos[c] Log[1 - b Cos[c] + Sqrt[1 + b^2 - 2 b Cos[c]]] Sin[c]^2)

Then the one over c:

```
intc = Limit[intb, b -> 1] - (Series[intb, {b, 0, 0}] // FullSimplify // Normal) //  FullSimplify
```

> -(1/(15 [Pi])) 2 (1 - 5 Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[c]] + 3 (-1 + Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[c]]) Cos[2 c] +  2 Cos[c] (Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[c]] + 3 (Log[1 - Cos[c]] - Log[1 + Sqrt[2 - 2 Cos[c]] - Cos[c]]) Sin[c]^2))

```
Integrate[intc, {c, 0, Pi}]
% // N
```

> 128/(45 [Pi])
>
> 0.905415

Note: In some cases one has to use Limit or even a series expansion to extract the correct value of the definite integral.

Comment: I'd like to inform that `Integrate[(4 a b/Pi) (a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c])^(1/2), {a, 0, 1}, {b, 
  0, 1}, Assumptions -> c > -Infinity]` produces a correct huge conditional expression in several hours  as `NIntegrate[%[[1]], {c, 0, Pi}]` confirms with the result `0.905415`.Unfortunately, `Integrate[%%[[1]], {c, 0, Pi}]` returns the input (I think because of `Arg[-E^(-I c) (-1 + E^(I c))^2]` and similar expressions.).

Comment: For those who wonder why "caution is advised" when using this method, read [this blog post from a Mathematica developer](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) (which I never miss an opportunity to link to.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Great link thanks! I was playing fast and loose with the calculus in the post, hence just the warning ;-)

Answer (score 10):

The unevaluated integral that *Mathematica* produced in the OP can be massaged a bit. First, note that due to symmetry, we can instead consider the integral

```
(16/π) Integrate[a b (a + b) EllipticE[(4 a b)/(a + b)^2], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]
```

and using [the conventional definition for `EllipticE`](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticE/07/01/01/0001/), we have

```
(16/π) Integrate[a b (a + b) Sqrt[1 - (4 a b)/(a + b)^2 Sin[t]^2],
                 {t, 0, π/2}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]
```

Due again to symmetry, this is equivalent to the integral

```
(8/π) Integrate[a b (a + b) Sqrt[1 - (4 a b)/(a + b)^2 Sin[t]^2],
                {t, -π/2, π/2}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]
```

and letting `w == Sin[t]`, we have

```
(8/π) Integrate[a b (a + b) Sqrt[(1 - (4 a b w^2)/(a + b)^2)/(1 - w^2)],
                {w, -1, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]
```

which happens to evaluate pretty quickly to `128/(45 π)`.

---

It should be noted that the equivalent integrals

```
16/π Integrate[a b (a + b) Sqrt[(1 - (4 a b)/(a + b)^2 w^2)/(1 - w^2)],
               {w, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]
```

and

```
4/π Integrate[a b (a + b) Sqrt[(1 - (4 a b)/(a + b)^2 w^2)/(1 - w^2)],
              {w, -1, 1}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

do not seem to finish as quickly (I waited ~ 2 minutes for each before giving up.)

Answer (score 8):

If you regard symmetry of integrand (two times integral from 0<b<a) and rearange to do integration over c at last, you get the result in a non splitted integration in 10 seconds.

Original integrations does not work may be because integrate can not handle the case a == b.

```
f[a_, b_, c_] = (4 a b/Pi) (a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b Cos[c])^(1/2);

f[a, b, c] == f[b, a, c]     (*   True   *)

{(int = 2*Integrate[f[a, b, c], {c, 0, Pi}, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, a}]), 
  int // N} // Timing

(*   {10.141, {128/(45 \[Pi]), 0.905415}}   *)
```

Comment: +1. Simply and strongly. On my comp `{138.766, {128/(45 \[Pi]), 0.905415}}`.